# Dynamically adding QLineEdits and then copy text from them to vector in right order

Tags: c++, qt

Here is how it looks at the beginning:

[image]

And after I can add random counts of line edits:

[image]

Or delete them:

[image]

The main purpose is the possibility to add or delete `QlineEdits` which stores user names and each `QlineEdit` adds a username to the vector in the right order (index) like this:

```
users =>
 [0] = "a";
 [1] = "b";
 [2] = "c";
 [3] = "d";  
 [4] = "e";
 [5] = "f";
 [6] = "g";
```

Here is the code :
**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QList>
#include <vector>
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void addbutton_Clicked();
    void deletebutton_Clicked();
    void lineedit_textChanged(QString text);

private:
    QVBoxLayout *middlelayout;
    QList<QLineEdit*> qlist;
    std::vector<QString> users;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget window = new QWidget(this);
    QVBoxLayout *mainlayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    middlelayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout *buttonlayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QPushButton *addbutton = new QPushButton;
    QPushButton *deletebutton = new QPushButton;

    addbutton->setText("ADD");
    deletebutton->setText("Delete");

    buttonlayout->addWidget(addbutton);
    buttonlayout->addWidget(deletebutton);
    buttonlayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    mainlayout->addLayout(buttonlayout);
    mainlayout->addLayout(middlelayout);
    window->setLayout(mainlayout);
    setCentralWidget(window);

    connect(addbutton, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(addbutton_Clicked()));
    connect(deletebutton, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(deletebutton_Clicked()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::addbutton_Clicked()
{
    QLineEdit *lineedit = new QLineEdit;
    qlist.push_back(lineedit);
    middlelayout->addWidget(lineedit);
    lineedit->setObjectName("lineedit"+QString::number(qlist.count()));

    users.resize(qlist.count());
    connect(lineedit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), SLOT(lineedit_textChanged(QString)));
}

void MainWindow::deletebutton_Clicked()
{
    QWidget *child;
    if(!middlelayout->isEmpty())
        if((child = middlelayout->takeAt(qlist.count()-1)->widget()) != 0) {
            delete child;
            qlist.removeLast();
    }
}

void MainWindow::lineedit_textChanged(QString text)
{
    unsigned int index = 0;
    QObject *obj = QObject::sender();
    QString senderobjName = obj->objectName();
    int isTextchanged = senderobjName.indexOf("lineedit") != -1;

    if(isTextchanged)
    {
        QStringList list = senderobjName.split("lineedit");
        index = list[1].toInt();
        users[index]=text;
    }
}
```

The code works fine but it seems that I'm doing it wrong and there is a better way.

Comment: From your screenshots it seems that if you add 100 line edits and then delete 99 the remaining line edit will be very far down.  Just a UX issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `MainWindow` destructor is empty, you can just omit it.

In `lineedit_textChanged`, you declare the `index` variable at the top,
but it's only used if the text has changed.
It would be better to declare it inside the `if` branch where you actually use it:

```
if (isTextchanged)
{
    QStringList list = senderobjName.split("lineedit");
    unsigned int index = list[1].toInt();
    users[index] = text;
}
```

This snippet can be a bit confusing without braces on the outer `if`:

> ```
> if(!middlelayout->isEmpty())
>     if((child = middlelayout->takeAt(qlist.count()-1)->widget()) != 0) {
>         delete child;
>         qlist.removeLast();
> }
> ```

It would be clearer this way:

```
if (!middlelayout->isEmpty()) {
    if ((child = middlelayout->takeAt(qlist.count()-1)->widget()) != 0) {
        delete child;
        qlist.removeLast();
    }
}
```